# Rails 6 internationalization - what has changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-6

I started a fresh new Rails 6 project and got stuck to figure out why what obviously just worked (it's not the first app I start), fails...
So I created a dummy simply  rails app with no additional gems and a `home#index` page:

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>
    <%= t('hello.world') %>
</p>
```

Then I added a translation for the above key to `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello !"
    world: "Hello World!"
```

and respected 1 tab indentation.
When navigating to `localhost:3000/home/index` I got the weird error:

```
/Users/serguei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/i18n-1.8.2/lib/i18n.rb:195: warning: The called method `translate' is defined here
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 6.2ms | Allocations: 3150)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5045)



ActionView::Template::Error (can not load translations from /Users/serguei/projects/rails/draft-app/config/locales/en.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 3>):
    1: <h1>Home#index</h1>
    2: <p>
    3:  <%= t('hello.world') %>
    4: </p>

app/views/home/index.html.erb:3
```

When changed the called translation to just `hello`:

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>
    <%= t('hello') %>
</p>
```

and removing the last line from the `en.yml` file:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello !"
```

it works.
Why so? What has changed since Rails 5 there? Can't we use nested translations anymore in locales files? [Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) have nothing special about that. Or am I missing something?

Adding [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem to the Gemfile didn't solve the problem.

- Rails version: 6.0.2.1
- Ruby version: ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin19]

Comment: Nested translation should work. Please, check quotes in `en.yml`, sometimes it is replaced with incorrect symbols on copypasting

Comment: I checked it, there was no copy/paste at all and everything seems to be correct, you can check the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/belgoros/1efe45609bbe2bf261567ca3ad79d9bc) I created. I also changed to use double quotes in the template: ` <%= t("hello.world") %>`, but no success :(.

Comment: Try to restart the server, maybe? I always run `spring stop && rails s` when have so weird errors

Comment: Still the same after restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to nest it, then you can't assign a string value to the parent, do this instead

```
en:
  hello:
    world: "Hello World!"
```

Then, in `erb`, this will work

```
<%= t('hello.world') %>
```

Give it a try.

Comment: My bad, that was that! Thank you. No idea why on Earth I left the value :).